# Matlab: RGB to HSV Values of specific pixels not working

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have been trying to get HSV values of few RGB pixels using the following code

```
im = imread('peppers.png'); %// example image
c = [12 146 410]; %// column coordinates of desired pixels
r = [104 156 129]; %// row coordinates of desired pixels
pixels = impixel(im,c,r); %// rgb values of pixels
hsv = rgb2hsv(pixels); %// convert to hsv
hue = hsv(:,1); %// hue is first column of hsv
```

But I get an error, `Valid colormaps cannot have values outside the range [0,1]`.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you checked the range of the values in `im`? Maybe they are integers from 0 - 255 instead of doubles from 0 - 1? If that's the case just use  `impixel(im/255,c,r)` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The range of the RGB colormap must be [0,1] (double) for rgb2hsv to work; your problem is the pixels matrix color range goes from 0 to 255 (int). You have to find a way to fix this. [im2double](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/im2double.html) might help.

See [the rgb2hsv documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2hsv.html) for details.

Also, I would recommend the use of [imfinfo](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imfinfo.html) to know the kind of image you are dealing with to then act accordingly in your code.